# Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused mongodb

Tags: mongodb, macos

I have 2 terminal windows, first to run the server, the second one to use as a client to connect to the db server.
I have successfully connected to my local mongoDB server.

**Terminal window 1**

```
bogdanmac:~ iliebogdanbarbulescu$ 
bogdanmac:~ iliebogdanbarbulescu$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.
```

Unfortunately, I can not access the database from the **client**.

**Terminal window 2**

```
ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$ pwd
/usr/local/var/mongodb
ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$ ls
WiredTiger              diagnostic.data
WiredTiger.lock             index-1-454351138292104502.wt
WiredTiger.turtle           index-3-454351138292104502.wt
WiredTiger.wt               index-5-454351138292104502.wt
WiredTigerLAS.wt            index-6-454351138292104502.wt
_mdb_catalog.wt             journal
collection-0-454351138292104502.wt  mongod.lock
collection-2-454351138292104502.wt  sizeStorer.wt
collection-4-454351138292104502.wt  storage.bson
ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-04-16T17:13:02.269+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-04-16T17:13:02.271+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-04-16T17:13:02.271+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$
```

**Logs at /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log**

```
2020-04-16T16:54:03.370+0100 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-04-16T16:54:03.373+0100 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-04-16T16:54:03.385+0100 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=76453 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=bogdanmac.mynet
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.5
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2261279b51ea13df08ae708ff278f0679c59dc32
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" } }
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2020-04-16T16:54:03.387+0100 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: I can see there is permission denied on the socket, could you please give permissions.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I don't know how to do that. Could you please tell me how? ```ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$ ls -ld /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  11  8 Jan 19:28 /tmp -> private/tmp
ilies-mbp:mongodb iliebogdanbarbulescu$ ls -ls /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
0 srwx------  1 root  wheel  0 16 Apr 16:20 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we can conclude this post with the solution to check the .sock file permission and change the permission of the .sock file.

```
   Change the permission of .sock file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Abhishek kumar , after changing the permission on the `.sock`file, I could start the client with the command `mongo`

- set the permissions of the .sock file to the current user:

  sudo chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock